# Displaying data table of 24 columns from MySQL to JavaScript DataTables to a webpage

Tags: javascript, mysql, datatables-1.10

Hi all I want to ask about javascript DataTables in displaying MySQL query table.

So this is MySQL query:

```
select LOT_LOCATION, `Zone Attribute`, a.LOTID, Design_ID, ifnul(Board_ID,'') as Board_ID1, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER, QA_PROCESS_TYPE, QA_PROCESS_NAME, CURRENT_QTY, Date, Temperature, Humidity, CONCAT(b.Zone1_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone1B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone1C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_1, CONCAT(b.Zone1_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone1B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone1C_Current, 'A') AS Current_1, CONCAT(b.Zone2_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone2B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone2C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_2, CONCAT(b.Zone2_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone2B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone2C_Current, 'A') AS Current_2, CONCAT(b.Zone3_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone3B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone3C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_3, CONCAT(b.Zone3_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone3B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone3C_Current, 'A') AS Current_3, CONCAT(b.Zone4_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone4B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone4C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_4, CONCAT(b.Zone4_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone4B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone4C_Current, 'A') AS Current_4, CONCAT(b.Zone5_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone5B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone5C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_5, CONCAT(b.Zone5_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone5B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone5C_Current, 'A') AS Current_5, CONCAT(b.Zone6_Voltage, 'V, ', b.Zone6B_Voltage, 'V, ',b.Zone6C_Voltage, 'V') AS Voltage_6, CONCAT(b.Zone6_Current, 'A, ', b.Zone6B_Current, 'A, ',b.Zone6C_Current, 'A') AS Current_6 from Lab_WIP_History a LEFT join chamber_data b ON a.LOT_LOCATION = b.Testtag  LEFT JOIN chamber_data_1 c ON a.LOTID = c.lotid
```

And this is MySQL table:

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute, LOTID, Design_ID, Board_ID1, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, QA_PROCESS_TYPE, QA_PROCESS_NAME, CURRENT_QTY, Date, Temperature, Humidity, Voltage_1, Current_1, Voltage_2, Current_2, Voltage_3, Current_3, Voltage_4, Current_4, Voltage_5, Current_5, Voltage_6, Current_6
'SGHAST.0064', '3', 'CVC66L2.11', 'J39E', '', '106544', 'ROBUSTNESS VALID', 'HAST 110C', '40', '2022-06-13 13:39:42', '109.98', '85.08', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.11A, A', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.1A, A', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.12A, A', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.12A, A', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.12A, A', '3.6V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.12A, A'
```

So what I want is to display all 24 columns in the same webpage. Below here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#elogbooktable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {url: "testing_getdetaildata.php", dataSrc: ""},
          'scrollCollapse': false,
          'deferRender':    true,
          'scroller':       true,
          'lengthMenu':     [[50, 75, 100, 200, -1], [50, 75, 100, 200, 'ALL']],
          'iDisplayLength': 50,
          'order': [[ 4, "asc" ]],
          'orderCellsTop' : true,
          'columnDefs': [ {
            'targets': 2,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[2]) {
                  $(td).html("<a href='http://mamweb.sing.micron.com/MAMWeb/bin/MAMWeb.pl?APP=MAMQASI&ACTION=REPORT&REPORTID=Status&MATYPE=78&FORMAT=HTML&CATEGORIES=ALL&ID="+rowData[2]+"' target='_blank'>"+rowData[2]+"</a>");
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 9,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[9]) {
                  $(td).text(moment(rowData[9]).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'));
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 10,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[10]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[10] + " C");
              }
            }
          } ,{
            'targets': 11,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[11]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[11] + " %RH");
              }
            }
          }],
          'filterDropDown': {                                       
                        columns: [
                            { 
                                idx: 5
                            }
                        ],
            bootstrap: true
                    },
         rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
            if(new Date(data[42]) < Date.now()){
            $(row).find('td:eq(42)').css('background-color', '#f8d7da');
          }
        },
    });

      <?php $i=13; 
     foreach($columns as $id=>$value) { 
         print "showHideColumn($id, $i);\n";
         $i++;
       } 
      ?>    

    //Add a text search box to each footer cell
    table.columns().every( function () {
      $(this.footer()).html("<input type='text' style='width:100%;' placeholder='Search'/>");
    });
    
    //Full table search functionality
    // Column search function       
    table.columns().every( function () {
      var that = this;
      $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
          that.search( this.value, true ).draw();
        }
      });
    });
    
    var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
     'buttons': ['pageLength','copyHtml5',
            {
              extend: 'excelHtml5',
            },
            {
              extend:  'print',
            }]
    }).container().appendTo($('#envdetail_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)'));
    
    setInterval( function () {
      table.ajax.reload();
    }, 300000 );
  
  });



  function showHideColumn(id, number) {
    var dtable = $('#elogbooktable').DataTable();
    
    if(dtable.column(number).visible() === true) {
      if($(id).attr("class").includes("btn-primary")) {
          $(id).removeClass("btn-primary");
          $(id).addClass("btn-default");
        }
        dtable.column(number).visible(false);
    }
    else {
      if($(id).attr("class").includes("btn-default")) {
          $(id).removeClass("btn-default");
          $(id).addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        dtable.column(number).visible(true);
    }
  }

 </script>
```

However, it does not display all 24 columns with the data but only the first 13 columns. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

UPDATED:

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600"/>
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta name="author" content="Arun Mohan(arunmohan)">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/sg/common/images/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sg/common/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css'/> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/sg/common/lib/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.css'/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sg/common/lib/flag-css/flag-css.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sg/common/css/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sg/common/css/common-style.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src="/sg/common/lib/jquery-3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/sg/common/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/polyfill/browser-polyfill.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/buttons.colVis.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/filter.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/jszip.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/pdfmake.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/vfs_fonts.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/buttons.html5.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/sg/common/lib/dt-1.10.19/js/buttons.print.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/sg/common/lib/moment-2.15.2/moment.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/sg/common/lib/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/process_verify.js?v=0.1'> 
</script>

<?php
 include_once("/u/sigqeng/public_html/common/common_micron.php");
 $title = "Elogbook";
?>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<?php
  $columns = array("qty"=>"Qty",
   "step"=>"Step", 
     "pkgtype"=>"Package Type",
     "numdie"=>"Number of Die in Pkg", 
     "leadcount"=>"Lead Count", 
   "pkgsize"=>"Package Size",
     "config"=>"Configuration Width",
   "rpmww"=>"RPM WW",
   "tcweight"=>"TC Weight",
   "qacont"=>"QA Contact",
   "qaprocessn"=>"QA Process Name"
     );
?>    

<style>
  .swal2-popup {
    font-size: 1.6rem !important;
  }
</style>

 
<!-- Matomo
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = window._paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['setUserId', "<?php echo $user; ?>"]);
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/home/analytics/piwik/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '3']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
End Matomo Code -->

</head>
<body>

<?php
  include("/home/sigqeng/public_html/common/menubar.inc");
?>

<div class="nav-section">
   <div style="float: right; text-align: center; padding-right: 12rem;">
     <span style="text-align: center">(Refresh Frequency: 5 minutes)</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid content">

    <!-- Process Verification -->
    <div class="well well-sm text-center">
      <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="lotid">Lot ID:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lotid" placeholder="Scan Lot ID" style="text-transform:uppercase">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="process">Process:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="process" placeholder="Scan Process" style="text-transform:uppercase">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="processVerify()">Verify</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="well well-sm">
      Show/Hide: <div class="btn-group text-center">
        <?php 
          $i = 13;
          foreach($columns as $id=>$value) {
        ?>
            <button id='<?php echo $id; ?>' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick='showHideColumn("#<?php echo $id; ?>", <?php echo $i; ?>);'><?php echo $value; ?></button>
        <?php 
          $i++; } 
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <div class="well well-sm-option text-center">
     <form class="chamber-type">
     <label for="chamber-type">Chamber Type:</label>
      <select id="filterbyChamber">
       <option value="">HAST</option>
       <option value="">BAKE</option>
       <option value="">TC</option>
       <option value="">THS</option>
       <option value="">THB</option>
       <option value="">TS</option>
      </select>
     </form> 
     <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="Date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" name="date" id="filterbyDATE">
     </form>
     <form class="shift">
      <label for="shift">Shift:</label>         
      <select id="filterbyShift">
       <option value="">1</option>
       <option value="">2</option>
      </select>
     </form> 
     </div>                     
      
    </div>
    
    <style>
    .chamber-type {
    display:inline-block;}
    form {
    display:inline-block;}
    </style>
    
    <div class="well well-sm">


    <table id='elogbooktable' class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed display nowrap' style="width: 100%;" role="grid" >
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Chamber</th>
              <th>Zone</th>
              <th>Lot ID</th>
              <th>Design ID</th>
              <th>Board ID</th>
              <th>QAWR</th>
              <th>QA Contact</th>
              <th>QA Process Name</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Temperature</th>
              <th>Humidity</th>
              <th>Voltage_1</th> 
              <th>Current_1</th>
              <th>Voltage_2</th> 
              <th>Current_2</th>
              <th>Voltage_3</th> 
              <th>Current_3</th>
              <th>Voltage_4</th> 
              <th>Current_4</th>
              <th>Voltage_5</th> 
              <th>Current_5</th>
              <th>Voltage_6</th> 
              <th>Current_6</th>            
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot style='display:table-header-group;'>
          <tr>
              <th>Chamber</th>
              <th>Zone</th>
              <th>Lot ID</th>
              <th>Design ID</th>
              <th>Board ID</th>
              <th>QAWR</th>
              <th>QA Contact</th>
              <th>QA Process Name</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Temperature</th>
              <th>Humidity</th>
              <th>Voltage_1</th> 
              <th>Current_1</th>
              <th>Voltage_2</th> 
              <th>Current_2</th>
              <th>Voltage_3</th> 
              <th>Current_3</th>
              <th>Voltage_4</th> 
              <th>Current_4</th>
              <th>Voltage_5</th> 
              <th>Current_5</th>
              <th>Voltage_6</th> 
              <th>Current_6</th>                                      
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#elogbooktable')
    .clone(true)
    .addClass('filters');  

    var table = $('#elogbooktable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {url: "testing_getdetaildata.php", dataSrc: ""},
          'scrollCollapse': false,
          'deferRender':    true,
          'scroller':       true,
          'lengthMenu':     [[50, 75, 100, 200, -1], [50, 75, 100, 200, 'ALL']],
          'iDisplayLength': 50,
          'order': [[ 4, "asc" ]],
          'orderCellsTop' : true,
          'columnDefs': [ {
            'targets': 2,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[2]) {
                  $(td).html("<a href='http://mamweb.sing.micron.com/MAMWeb/bin/MAMWeb.pl?APP=MAMQASI&ACTION=REPORT&REPORTID=Status&MATYPE=78&FORMAT=HTML&CATEGORIES=ALL&ID="+rowData[2]+"' target='_blank'>"+rowData[2]+"</a>");
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 9,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) 
     {
              if(rowData[9]) {
                  $(td).text(moment(rowData[9]).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'));
              }
            }
          }, {
            'targets': 10,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[10]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[10] + " C");
              }
            }
          } ,{
            'targets': 11,
            'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData[11]) {
                  $(td).text(rowData[11] + " %RH");
              }
            }
          }],
          'filterDropDown': {                                       
                        columns: [
                            { 
                                idx: 5
                            }
                        ],
            bootstrap: true
                    },
         rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
            if(new Date(data[42]) < Date.now()){
            $(row).find('td:eq(42)').css('background-color', '#f8d7da');
          }
        },
    });

      <?php $i=13; 
     foreach($columns as $id=>$value) { 
         print "showHideColumn($id, $i);\n";
         $i++;
       } 
      ?>    

    //Add a text search box to each footer cell
    table.columns().every( function () {
      $(this.footer()).html("<input type='text' style='width:100%;' placeholder='Search'/>");
    });
    
    //Full table search functionality
    // Column search function       
    table.columns().every( function () {
      var that = this;
      $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
          that.search( this.value, true ).draw();
        }
      });
    });
    
    var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
     'buttons': ['pageLength','copyHtml5',
            {
              extend: 'excelHtml5',
            },
            {
              extend:  'print',
            }]
    }).container().appendTo($('#envdetail_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)'));
    
    setInterval( function () {
      table.ajax.reload();
    }, 300000 );
  
  });



  function showHideColumn(id, number) {
    var dtable = $('#elogbooktable').DataTable();
    
    if(dtable.column(number).visible() === true) {
      if($(id).attr("class").includes("btn-primary")) {
          $(id).removeClass("btn-primary");
          $(id).addClass("btn-default");
        }
        dtable.column(number).visible(false);
    }
    else {
      if($(id).attr("class").includes("btn-default")) {
          $(id).removeClass("btn-default");
          $(id).addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        dtable.column(number).visible(true);
    }
  }

 </script>
 
 
 </body>
</html>

<script>
    var searchFilter = () => {
        let selectedColor = document.getElementById("filterByChamber").value;
        const input = document.querySelector(".form-control");
        let textBox= input.value;
        const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
        for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body");
            if ((cards[i].classList.contains(selectedColor) || selectedColor=="") && title.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(textBox.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                cards[i].classList.remove("d-none");
            } else {
                cards[i].classList.add("d-none");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried using "scrollX" : true in the datatables characteristics/function but it does not work

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to make it easier for the community to provide a good answer for you. For example, you have not show us (a) the HTML you are using; (b) the text of the JSON response from your Ajax request; (c) the libraries you are using - and in what order; (d) any error messages in the browser console. Also if you have tried something, then don't add that as a comment, it's better to add it to the body of the question (at the end), as an update.

Comment: @andrewJames sorry am new to stackoverflow! a. I added the html code in the question. b. It is successful so there is no error message (from the inspect, network). c. jquery, pollyfill, bootstrap, buttons, datatables, etc. (u can find in the first part of html code) d. no error because it runs successfully only that it can display 13 instead of 24 columns.

Comment: Item (b) is not asking for an error message. It is asking for the JSON response (added to the question as formatted text). We need this so we can see what the raw data looks like that you are trying to display, and what structure that data has.

Comment: Also, I have to believe that you can do a great deal to simplify your example (that is the "minimal" in [mre]) and still show us what the problem is. Do you really need to provide an example containing all those additional libraries (e.g. sweetalert and so on)? Are they _directly_ relevant to the problem you are facing? If not, then remove them from the example in the question. Remove _everything_ from the example which is not relevant to the problem. Take another look at the MRE guidance. (You may even solve your own problem in the process of creating a true MRE.)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Change this code:

```
      <?php $i=13; 
 foreach($columns as $id=>$value) { 
     print "showHideColumn($id, $i);\n";
     $i++;
   } 
  ?>
```

To this:

```
  <?php $i=24; 
 foreach($columns as $id=>$value) { 
     print "showHideColumn($id, $i);\n";
     $i++;
   } 
  ?>
```